# How to replace some thousands of external images inside wordpress database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, csv

In our wp database:
We have external img srcs like these as custom fields inside thousands of posts:
They are all broken because remote server deleted them.

```
Post1: http://thumb-v.example.com/t/918/2_5357918.jpg

Post2: https://thumb-v.example.com/t/219/200/3_8165219.jpg
```

Post 3: Similar
Post 4: Similar Post 5,6,..:... etc.

Just this part is same: `thumb-v.example.com/t/`

So how to replace all of them with just one custom "not found" image file which is exist on our server?
Like changing them with: `https://oursite.com/imagenotfound.jpg` ?

Comment: Could you not write a simple program to loop through all the image references, find those that match the indicated pattern, and replace the reference in your database?  It doesn't matter how slow or inefficient it is, it will only run once.  Right?

Comment: But i dont know how to write. Yes it will only run once.

Comment: You don't know how to write a query for your database?

Comment: Dont know. How to write for problems such as this?

Comment: I apologize, but we can't help you here.  This site's purpose is to answer specific questions about the software you write.  If you don't know how to write a query for your DB, then you probably can't even tell someone enough to help them write the software for you - and providing tutorials about MySQL and PHP is beyond the scope of SO.  You should speak with whomever it is who maintains your website.